# RecyclerView doesn't update at all

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have simple task, but I don't understand why it doesn't work. I need to place `images` in a `GridView`. I decided to use the `RecyclerView`. So I have some where I've placed it:

```
  <LinearLayout
  ..>
  ...

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ebebeb">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my `Activity` I declare:

```
    images = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view1);

    adapter = new ImageGridAdapter(Place.this, images);
    manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(3, 8, true));    //   for grid with equal spacing
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When All my `views` and `objects` are initialized, using `Retrofit2` I get data  and try to update adapter, created before.

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PlaceModel> call, Response<PlaceModel> response) {
            placeProperties = response.body().getData();
            images = placeProperties.getPhotos();
            System.out.println("size = " + images.size());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateUI(placeProperties);

                    images.clear();
                    images.addAll(placeProperties.getPhotos());
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(0, images.size());
                    //just adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); also doesn't give result;

                }
            });

        }
```

Nevertheless, my `updateUI` method works fine, and updates views with data  from `placeProperties` object. And the `image.size()>1`.

Here's an `Adapter` class. https://gist.github.com/burnix/aa27efe9586213852c108f3d79f3f69d

According to the logs, my `onBindViewHolder` method doesn't work.

What did I miss? Why my RecyclerView doesn't show any picture?

P.S. I've read every similar question and those doesn't help. Hope I'm just tired and neglecting something very simple...

Comment: Try commenting out this line in onResponse(): `//images = placeProperties.getPhotos();`

Comment: @DanielNugent , you're so smart and attentive! It's work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that you're re-assigning the reference for the data source of the RecylerView.

All you need to do is remove this line:

```
images = placeProperties.getPhotos();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation. I've got it!